# Query system tables for multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework to generate my tables from my model, and every now and again I get a problem with multiple cascade paths. e.g:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.SurveyorSurveys_dbo.Surveys_Survey_ID' on table
>   'SurveyorSurveys' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

I find it quite time consuming working out where the cascade paths are to this new table, so that I can remove one of the cascade deletes. I think it would be really useful if I could run a query on the system tables that showed me the full paths that were involved. Has anyone worked out how to do that?

For example I have this sql:

```
SELECT
    ro.name referenced_object,
    po.name parent_object,
    fk.name foreign_key
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects po
    ON fk.parent_object_id = po.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects ro
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = ro.object_id
WHERE delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE'
and (po.name = 'Surveys' or po.name = 'Surveyors'')
ORDER BY ro.name
```

But this only takes me up one level in the hierarchy, it might be better to remove a cascade delete at a higher level, so I end up adjusting and re-running the sql until I work out the full path

Comment: Are you just trying to see cascade paths of a table  ?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. It's a table that is created in a migration, and the migration fails, leaving me without the table. So I need to look at the cascade paths of more than one existing table that will link to the new table. In this example, I'm creating a many-to-many relationship between the `Surveys` and `Surveyors` tables, and that will result in an error when I create the `SurveyorSurveys` table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically something to do with a [recursive query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

First a few words to clarify the column names in `sys.all_objects`:

- `parent_object_id` refers to the object *owning the foreign key*, so it's not the parent in the relationship, it's the child.
- `referenced_object_id` is the parent in the relationship.

Knowing this, we can write a recursive query that collects trees of foreign key relationships by connecting the child in the previous level with the parent in the subsequent level:

```sql
WITH [Cascades] AS(
    SELECT
        fk.referenced_object_id AS [RootId],
        fk.parent_object_id AS [ChildId],
        fk.referenced_object_id AS [ParentId],
        fk.name foreign_key,
        1 AS [Level]
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    WHERE delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Cascades].[RootId],
        fk.parent_object_id,
        fk.referenced_object_id,
        fk.name foreign_key,
        [Cascades].[Level] + 1
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN [Cascades] ON [Cascades].[ChildId] = fk.referenced_object_id
    WHERE delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE'
)
SELECT [root].Name AS [Root],
       po.Name AS [Parent],
       co.Name AS [Child],
       foreign_key,
       cs.[Level]
FROM [Cascades] cs
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects [root] ON cs.[RootId] = [root].object_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects po ON cs.ParentId = po.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects co ON cs.ChildId = co.object_id
WHERE [root].name = 'Surveys'
ORDER BY [Root], [Parent], [Level], [Child]
```

If I execute the query in a simple tree-level hierarchy, the output is:

```
Root Parent Child foreign_key Level
-----------------------------------
A    A      B1    FK_B1_A     1
A    A      B2    FK_B2_A     1
A    B1     C     FK_C_B1     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative sql based on Gert's excellent answer. This one lets me specify the leaf and shows the full cascade path on each row

```
WITH Cascades
AS (SELECT
    fk.parent_object_id,
    fk.referenced_object_id,
    fk.name foreign_keys,
    CAST(ro.name + ' -> ' + po.name AS nvarchar(256)) path,
    1 AS level
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects po
    ON fk.parent_object_id = po.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects ro
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = ro.object_id
WHERE delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE'
-- specifying leaf instead of root:
AND po.name IN ('Surveys', 'Surveyors', 'surveyorsurveys') 
UNION ALL SELECT
    fk.parent_object_id,
    fk.referenced_object_id,
    CAST(fk.name + ' -> ' + Cascades.foreign_keys as nvarchar(128)),
    CAST(ro.name + ' -> ' + cascades.path AS nvarchar(256)),
    cascades.level + 1
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects po
    ON fk.parent_object_id = po.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects ro
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = ro.object_id
    INNER JOIN cascades
    ON cascades.referenced_object_id = fk.parent_object_id
WHERE delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE')
SELECT
    path,
    foreign_keys,
    level
FROM Cascades
ORDER BY path
```